# cakephp query find_in_set on single column with multiple searched keywords not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.x

I want to find all the records from column who have any keyword match with column data:

It works fine if searching single search keyword in column having comma separated values like below code: Cakephp 3.4 version

```
$posts = TableRegistry::get('Posts');
                $search_keywords = array_filter(explode(' ', $search_string));
                $option = [
                      'contain' => false,
                      'conditions' => [
                        "find_in_set('New', Posts.title)",
                      ],
                      'order' => ['Posts.created DESC'] 
                  ];
        $allpost = $posts->find('all',$option)->toArray();
```

Note: i want all the words from string should be search with column title, its not mandatory to have comma separated records:

```
$search_keyword = "New car in new delhi";
```

so i want code to be like below :

```
$search_keyword = "New car in new delhi";
$search_keywords = array_filter(explode(' ', $search_string));
                $option = [
                      'contain' => false,
                      'conditions' => [
                        "find_in_set({$search_keywords}, `Posts`.title)",
                      ],
                      'order' => ['Posts.created DESC'] 
                  ];
        $allpost = $posts->find('all',$option)->toArray();
```

Great Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

First make column fulltext index then add below code:

```
$search_string = "New car in new delhi";
$option = [
                      'contain' => false,
                      'conditions' => [
                        "MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$search_string')"
                      ],
                      'order' => ['Posts.created DESC'] 
                  ];
        $allpost = $posts->find('all',$option)->toArray();
```

Comment: Please, **_never ever insert (user)data into queries directly_**, that's a possible SQL injection vulnerability! **_Always_** use safe `key => value` conditions or bindings! **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention**

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me how to write this query in cake syntax.

Comment: Please check the link, there's an example showing your exact case.

Comment: Is that a statement? Or a question? Or...? The value binding example shows exactly what you're doing here, ie using `MATCH AGAINST`: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#binding-values**

Comment: i tried in the same way but not binding keywords to title column.